# Django CharField limitations

Tags: python, django

how can I specify a blacklist for a CharField. However I want the blacklist to be effective in the Django admin panel aswell...otherwise I would just validate it in the view.

By blacklist I mean values that can't be used. I also set unique for the value but I would like to disable a few strings aswell.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would override the model's save() method and the to be inserted value against a blacklist before calling the parent class' save() method.

Something like that (simplified):

```
class BlackListModel(models.Model):   
   blacklist = ['a', 'b', 'c']

   # your model fields definitions...

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.blacklist_field in self.blacklist:
            raise Exception("Attempting to save a blacklisted value!")
        return super(BlackListModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

That way it works in all of your applications.

Answer (score 4):

Since we're a few years later, you should write a custom blacklist validator:

```
from django.db import models    
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_blacklist(value):
    if value in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
        raise ValidationError(
            "'a', 'b' and 'c' are prohibited!",
            params={'value': value},
        )

class MyModel(models.Model):
    even_field = models.CharField(max_length=200, validators=[validate_even])
```

See: [Django Validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/) for full documentation.

Comment: It's worth a mention that MyModel.create('a') would raise no ValidationErrors while overriding .save() solves this

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box. You would have to write a [custom form field](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#ref-forms-validation) or otherwise add [custom admin handling](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls) to do admin-level validation. To do it at the database level, I suspect you would need to set up some kind of trigger and stored procedure, but that's not my area so I'll leave that to others.